# Html in microsoft visual studio 2010?

Tags: html

I have microsoft visual studio 2010 and I'm just wondering how I can start an html project in it, or is that even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start an ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio 2010 and delete all of the .ASPX files and create .HTML files.

The IDE has great support for HTML and JavaScript (at least for jQuery), but it isn't focused for your usage case.

The only persons generally using Visual Studio for HTML related work is ASP.NET developers like myself. It is very "heavy" for pure HTML work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio you can probably have access to Microsoft Expression Web which does exactly what you want.